# How can auto assign customer ticket in HYBRIS?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

Someone do you know how can auto assigne customer ticket?For example customer has entered a new support ticket and I am a customer support manager then I can configure the department to which each issue type/category is assigned to. Now when customer has entered a new support ticket from storefront and I am a customer support manager or agent it does'n matter, ticket is assigned to customersupportagent group. How can change to be assigned to customersupportmanager group? I'm new in hybris

Answer (score 1):

**CsTicket** item **assignedGroup** property is optional. hybris hasn't got configuration for this. But there is bean in ext-commerce/customerticketingfacades/resources/customer-ticketingfacades-spring.xml with name **ticketAssostaionPopulator**. You can try to override this bean for assigning default assignedGroup.

If this not work you need to override controller which is setting this as default group.